# How to solve the fractions for this limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{5n})^{n}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

To solve this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{5n}\bigg)^{n}$$

I used the rule $a^b = e^{b\ln(a)}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n\cdot\ln\big(1+\frac{1}{5n}\big)}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{\ln\big(1+\frac{1}{5n}\big)}{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Now use L'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{5n^{2}}}{1+\frac{1}{5n}}}{-\frac{1}{n^{2}}}}$$

Comment: **HINT**: Do the limit without the exponential in there.

Comment: Lol I have never seen so many fractions upon fractions. Could you improve the formatting by using $exp(...)$ rather than $e^{...}$ for big expressions?

Comment: $\lim _{ n\to \infty  } (1+\frac { 1 }{ 5n } )^{ n }=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left( (1+\frac { 1 }{ 5n } )^{ 5n } \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 5 }  } } ={ e }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 5 }  }$

Comment: @haqnatural How were you allowed to put $\frac{1}{5}$ up there?

Comment: it seems you  unfamiliar with the limit $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ n }  \right)  }^{ n } } $

Comment: @haqnatural I know that represents e I am just unfamiliar of the algebraic transformation.

Comment: Upon further inspection it's clear. Just wouldn't have thought to do it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{5n}\right)^{\!n}=
\sqrt[5]{\left(1+\frac{1}{5n}\right)^{\!5n}}
$$
What's the limit inside the radical?

Comment: Most logical path in my opinion :-)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\ln (1+x)}{x}=1.$$

when $$n\to+\infty,  x=\frac {1}{n}\to 0$$

You will find $e^{\frac {1}{5} }$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{5n}\right)^n$ and $b_n=a_n^5$. We have that $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a subsequence of the converging sequence $\{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\}_{n\geq 1}$. Since the limit of the last sequence is $e$, we have $b_n\to e$, hence
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n = \color{red}{e^{1/5}} $$
because $a_n\geq 1$ and the function $x\to x^5$ is continuous and invertible (with a continuous inverse function) over $[1,+\infty)$. There is no need to introduce logarithms or de l'Hospital theorem: it is enough to exploit the definitions and the main properties of converging sequences, limits and $e$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that for all $x \in \mathbb R$ we have that $e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac xn)^n$. Thus we have that:

\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{5n})^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{n})^n = e^{\frac15}.
\end{align*}